# React Material UI EVERYTHING IN UPPERCASE

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, uppercase

Is there a way to display all text in uppercase (textTransform), one for all, in the theme description.
uppercase static text, inputs, and fetched data?

Comment: What happens if you use `* { text-transform: uppercase; }` ?

Answer (score 6):

You can set the `textTransform` on the container class using `makeStyles`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        textTransform: "uppercase"
    }
});
```

And inside your application use the `root` class in your wrapper element:

```
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>

    </div>
);
```

In case you want this on specific Mui elements you can use the `createMuiTheme` and using the `overrides` you can specify css values on specific elements:

```
const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiPaper: {
            root: {
                textTransform: "uppercase"
            }
        },
        MuiBreadcrumbs: {
            root: {
                textTransform: "uppercase"
            }
        }
    }
});

return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
        ...
    </MuiThemeProvider>
);
```